# nfs boot hangs after systemd-networkd starts

Tags: boot, nfs, systemd-networkd

I am trying to nfs-boot a linux managed with systemd, via tftp kernel + nfs rootfs, my bootargs:

```
root=/dev/nfs rw nfsroot=192.168.0.10:/nfsroot/rootfs,nolock ip=192.168.0.60:192.168.0.10:192.168.0.10:255.255.255.0
```

Both kernel and rootfs loads successfully and the system is running, until `systemd-networkd` starts. After that, I can **not ping** the machine and NFS mount hangs (obviously).

I tried to add network config for `systemd-networkd` to initialize the network, but it does not work.

The serial console log:

```
         Starting Network Service...
...
[  OK  ] Started Network Service.
[  OK  ] Reached target Network.
...
[  *   39.330000] nfs: server 192.168.0.10 not responding, still trying
```

The network config:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0
[Network]
Address=192.168.0.60/24
Gateway=192.168.0.10
[Route]
Gateway=192.168.0.10
Destination=192.168.0.0
```

I wonder why `systemd-networkd.service` breaks the network when the system is started via nfs?

I guess when `networkd` starts, it withdraws the ip address, and then tries to read the config file. At this time the nfs mount already breaks, and it does not have a chance to read the config file.

If my guess is true, how to "fix" or "workaround" this issue?

Comment: I guess when `networkd` starts, it withdraws the ip address, and then tries to read the config file. At this time the nfs mount already breaks, and it does not have a chance to read the config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that `systemd-networkd` provides an option to not releasing the IP.

Adding below in the config

```
[DHCP]
CriticalConnection=true
```

Then the IP will not be released and NFS will not hang.

Comment: By way of an update: from systemd v243, the `CritialConnection` setting has been deprecated; now there's a `KeepConfiguration` setting instead. Check the `systemd.network` manual page for details.

Answer (score 2):

Though it was a question 2 years ago, I still googled here. And I finally get a better solution from [NFS ROOT WITH SYSTEMD](http://www.kieranbingham.co.uk/nfs-root-with-systemd/)

```
[Match]
Name=eth*
KernelCommandLine=!nfsroot
```

Comment: But the author said @Mine 's solution is "an alternative method as well". I will confirm whether linux kernel parameter 'ip=dhcp' works for multiple ethernet cards. If not, this patch blocks multiple enthernet cards got ips expect the first one.